# Multiple action buttons each with explanations

Tags: forms, interaction-design, dialog, call-to-action

If I intend for a user to click one of four related but different submit buttons on a page and I also plan on having a brief paragraph explaining what each button is supposed to accomplish, what is the "best" way of presenting these action buttons along with their respective text?

The two ideas I have in mind are as follows:

1. A separate button for each action, when the user makes their choice, a dialog box is shown containing the explanation and Cancel and Submit buttons.
2. A tab for each submission, then the explanation text and a Submit button within each tab area.

I wondered if there is a "standard" way of doing such a display or other considerations better than the list two

Comment: Why 4 submit buttons? You should have only one. Make users choose an option based on that explanation you mention then simply click submit